# Print out all primes in interval

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me why the print statement in reached for every iteration of the for loop, even though the conditions aren't met?

```
from math import *
def sumOfPrimes():
    divisor = 2
    for n in range(2, 100):
        if n % divisor != 0 and n != divisor:         
            divisor += 1
            if divisor == n:
                print (n, divisor)
                divisor = 2
        else:
            divisor = 2
```

Comment: `for n in range(2, int(sqrt(n))):` are you sure you want this? What's your expected conditions as you say "...even though the conditions aren't met"?

Comment: In my honest opinion, your logic is too complicated for this problem. A double nested for loop and a list to to keep track of the primes you discover is sufficient. Your second `for` loop should consist of the primes you append to this list as you discover them.

Answer (score 2):

lets look at the number 3. 
the divisor is still 2.

```
(n % divisor != 0 and n != divisor) = (3 % 2 != 0 and 3 != 2) = True

divisor += 1 (divisor is now 3.)

(divisor == n) = (3 == 3) = true

print (n, divisor) = print(3,3)
```

now at number 4:

```
(n % divisor != 0 and n != divisor) = (4 % 3 != 0 and 4 != 3) = True

divisor += 1 (divisor is now 4.)

(divisor == n) = (4 == 4) = true

print (n, divisor) = print(4,4)
```

and so on.
that's why the print statement is reached for every iteration of the for loop.

if you want to calculate the sum of the primes from 2 to 100 you can use another loop with another var, which run from 2 to sqrt(n) and checks if the number is dividable with any of them. that way you can determinate if the number is prime or not, and add only primes to the sum.

```
from math import *
def sumOfPrimes(Number):
    Sum = 0
    for n in range(2, Number+1): #range doesnt count the last number so I added 1 to Number.
        if sqrt(n)<2: Sum += n;
        else:
            prime = True;
            for i in range(2, int(sqrt(n))+1): #range takes only int, the +1 is like the previous one.
                if n % i == 0:
                    prime = False; #the number is not prime.
            if prime: Sum+=n; print n;
    return Sum;

print sumOfPrimes(100);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        if n % divisor != 0 and n != divisor:
```

`n % divisor != 0` is true if `divisor` *isn't* a divisor of n. For example, this will be true if `divisor` is 2 and `n` is 3. On every iteration of the loop after the first, this will trigger, because `divisor` will be `n-1`.

```
            divisor += 1
```

On every iteration of the loop after the first, `divisor` will be `n-1` right before this line and `n` right after. I don't know why you're doing this.

```
            if divisor == n:
```

This will be true, so

```
                print (n, divisor)
```

this will happen.

Answer (score 1):

You are -- I would imagine unintentionally -- reusing the variable called `n` for two different things. One is the argument to the function, and the other is the loop variable:

```
def sumOfPrimes(n):
    ...
    for n in range(2, int(sqrt(n))):
        ...
```

You need to figure out which is which, and separate them by renaming one of them throughout the code.

Comment: edited, but the print statement is still reached for every value of n